# exclude jar from compile

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have a compile configuration on my build.gradle from a third-party team repository.

```
compile ('com.app:mycustomvideoplayer:1.0')
```

Which use another third party lib from a jar file.

```
 mycustomvideoplayer/libs/somesdk.jar
```

I need to disable access for this jar (somesdk) on my project, with no effects on the main configuration (app:mycustomvideoplayer).

Comment: Fork the 3rd party repository and remove the requirement for somesdk from your fork.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exclude`, like this if it being resolved by gradle

```
exclude group: 'mycustomvideoplayer', module: 'somesdk'
```